# How to pair two anonymous users together in php

Tags: php

I am developing a two player game. users can play anonymously without registering.

--> user sends a request to server for game partner and waits for 1 min.

-->If with in 1 min any other user sends the request to server i need to pair both users together.

--> else end the request.

Here my problem is i am new to PHP how to find to user sends request to play the game and how to pair both of them together.

Could you please help me to solve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP is asking for code

Comment: your problem doesnt sound like PHP but more of object oriented design...try on programer.stackexchange :)

Comment: Create a session as soon an user wants to start the game insert that session into a table `new_sessions` and have another table with `coupled_sessions` of course you need some timestamp in the tables. But I would do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is about detecting anonymous users you should use PHP session.